# rgdal install fails for version 1.5-17 and 1.5-18 but 1.5-16 works

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm getting the following error when I try to install rgdal 1.5-17 or -18, -16 works:

```
In file included from proj6.cpp:5:0:
proj6.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* get_source_crs(SEXP)’:
proj6.cpp:258:58: error: ‘PJ_WKT2_2019’ was not declared in this scope
         COPY_TO_USER_STRING(proj_as_wkt(ctx, target_crs, PJ_WKT2_2019, NULL)));
                                                          ^
/opt/R/R_4.0.0/lib64/R/include/Rdefines.h:191:39: note: in definition of macro ‘COPY_TO_USER_STRING’
 #define COPY_TO_USER_STRING(x) mkChar(x)
                                       ^
```

GEOS 3.7.2, GDAL 3.0.1, PROJ 6.2.0

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using GEOS 3.7.2, GDAL 3.0.1, PROJ 6.2.0, they are working with rgdal 1.5-16, but when I try to upgrade they fail.

Comment: From your post, I do have the versions required: GDAL 3.01 and PROJ 6.2